# Exporting table from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 5.6 (Error)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, phpmyadmin

While running the following queries on MySQL 5.6.39,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sessions`;

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `payload` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `sessions_id_unique` (`id`);
```

I get the following error :

[image]

However, if I remove the part that says `COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, everything works fine. Why is this happening ?

The above query is an export from **phpMyAdmin (MySQL version 5.7.22)**

Comment: Yash - Any chance of accepting my answer below assuming it worked to resolve the issue by turning  the upper right hand side check mark from grey to green in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `id` column is `varchar(255)` so from your config file enable the [`innodb_large_prefix`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) on this instance of **MySQL** to resolve the problem but per the below, this explains why this is occurring from my interpretation.

You can run `show variables` and see if the `innodb_large_prefix` if **ON** or **OFF**.

---

### [Maximums and Minimums](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

- > By default, the index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes. See
  >   [Section 13.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)”. For example, you might hit
  >   this limit with a [column prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_column_prefix) index of more than 255 characters on a
  >   `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` column, assuming a `utf8mb3` character set and the
  >   maximum of 3 bytes for each character. When the `innodb_large_prefix`
  >   configuration option is enabled, the index key prefix length limit is
  >   raised to 3072 bytes for InnoDB tables that use [DYNAMIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_dynamic_row_format) or [COMPRESSED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_compressed_row_format)
  >   row format.
  >
  > Attempting to use an index key prefix length that exceeds the limit
  >   returns an error. To avoid such errors in replication configurations,
  >   avoid enabling `innodb_large_prefix` on the master if it cannot also be
  >   enabled on slaves.
  >
  > The limits that apply to index key prefixes also apply to full-column
  >   index keys.

Answer (score 0):

5.5 and 5.6 have the "767 error"; 5.7 gets around it.

- Can you live with 191 characters instead of 255?
- Will utf8 suffice instead of utf8mb4?

Here are details on 3 ways to get around "767" if you have 5.6 that might work for you: 
 http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

(Prefix indexing is not a reasonable option for the `PRIMARY KEY`.)